# how to convert to "C" format by using std::bind member function of a class as a thread portal function?

Tags: c++

if there is function for thread creating

```
int thread_create( void*(*create_cb)(void*), void* arg);
```

there is a class example which have a member function:

```
void* example::startupTask(void *args);
```

how to convert to "C" format by using std::bind member function of a class as a thread portal function?

```
std::function<void* (void*)> func = std::bind(&example::startupTask, this, std::placeholders::_1);
auto rtn = thread_create((*func.target<std::_Bind <void*(example::*(example*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(void*)> >()), nullptr);
```

this code can run crashed.

Comment: Why not use a standard C++ thread object ([`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread))?

Comment: to adapt old API, std::thread has no issue

Comment: Do you need additional parameters passed to `startupTask`? If not, simply pass `this` as `arg` and call the function that way.

Comment: Note that the names `_Bind` and `_Placeholder` are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code; they're not portable. Use `std::bind` and `std::placeholders::_1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. `std::bind` returns a CPP object with `operator()`, so it acts like a function. `thread_create` expects a pointer to a memory address.

Instead, you should use the additional parameter in `thread_create` to pass the context for the function.